# One-way platform collisions in Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I am making a Doodle Jump clone game in Swift and the issue is that when the player jumps, it hits its head on the bottom of the platform and doesn't pass through. How can I make the player pass over the platform and jump through them? I have my code here:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hero");
    var stepSizeTest = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "step");
    var start = false;
    var jumpSpeed = CGFloat(0);
    var gravity = CGFloat(0);
    var stepPositionDivision:CGFloat = 0 //allows the step to spawn on specific places on y axes
    var setpPositionHeightIncrease:CGFloat = 0;

    var positionX:CGFloat = 0;
    var timeInterval:NSTimeInterval = 0;
    var CurTime:NSTimeInterval = 0;
    var TimeWhenThePreviousStepSpawned:NSTimeInterval = 0;
    var standart:Bool = false;
    var move:Bool = false;
    var oneJumpOnly:Bool = false;
    var cracked:Bool = false;
    var jumped:Bool = false;

    struct PhysicsCategory{
        static var None: UInt32 = 0;
        static var step: UInt32 = 0b1;
        static var hero: UInt32 = 0b10;
        static var All: UInt32 = UInt32.max;
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        var contactBody1: SKPhysicsBody;
        var contactBody2: SKPhysicsBody;
        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask){
            contactBody1 = contact.bodyA;
            contactBody2 = contact.bodyB;
        }
        else{
            contactBody1 = contact.bodyB;
            contactBody2 = contact.bodyA;
        }

        if (contactBody1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.step && contactBody2.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.hero){
            jumpSpeed = CGFloat(self.frame.size.height*0.01320422535);

        }
//        if (contactBody1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.ground && contactBody2.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.hero){
//
//        }
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        stepPositionDivision = self.frame.size.height/23;

        jumpSpeed = CGFloat(self.frame.size.height*0.01320422535);
        gravity = CGFloat(self.frame.size.height*(-0.0003521126761));

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,0);

        let sceneBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame);
        sceneBody.friction = 0;
        self.physicsBody = sceneBody;


        self.hero.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5);
        self.hero.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.size.width/2, y:self.hero.size.height/2);
        self.hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.hero.size)
        self.hero.physicsBody?.restitution = 1;
        self.hero.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false;
        self.hero.physicsBody?.friction = 0;
        self.hero.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.hero;
        self.hero.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.step;
        self.hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.step;

        self.addChild(self.hero);
    }

    func ranPositionX() -> CGFloat{
        let stepSise = UInt32(self.stepSizeTest.size.width)
        let posX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.width) - stepSise) + stepSise
        return CGFloat(posX)
    }

    func stepSpawn(){
        if (setpPositionHeightIncrease < self.frame.size.height){
            let step = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "step");
            let posX = ranPositionX()

            step.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5);
            step.position = CGPoint(x:posX, y:setpPositionHeightIncrease);
            step.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: step.size);
            step.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false;
            step.physicsBody?.dynamic = true;
            step.physicsBody?.friction = 0;
            step.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.step;
            step.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None;
            step.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.hero;

            self.addChild(step);
            setpPositionHeightIncrease += stepPositionDivision
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */
        for touch in touches {

        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */

        self.hero.position.y += jumpSpeed
        jumpSpeed += gravity

        if (start == false){
            //self.hero.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 40))
            start = true;
        }
        stepSpawn()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to enumerate over all the nodes the scene, and if they are above the player, switch their collisionBitMask so that they do not collide, and if they are below the player, switch it so they do.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to toggle the appropriate collision bit(s) on/off, if the hero is falling or jumping. The hero is falling if its velocity's `dy` property is less than zero and jumping (or bouncing up) if `dy` is greater than zero. Here's an example of how to do this:

```
// Add this to the update method
if let body = hero.physicsBody {
    let dy = body.velocity.dy
    if dy > 0 {
        // Prevent collisions if the hero is jumping
        body.collisionBitMask &= ~PhysicsCategory.step
    }
    else {
        // Allow collisions if the hero is falling
        body.collisionBitMask |= PhysicsCategory.step
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a decent approach, which I've used myself if a few projects. One catch, though: if the hero is moving sideways while falling, his side can collide with that of the platform. To get around that I combine the above approach with minimal-height physics bodies: only the top edge of the platform needs a body, not its whole visible shape, and only the bottom edge of the hero sprite. (If other parts of the hero need to collide with enemies or whatever, use a separate body that doesn't collide with floors.)

Comment: &= ~PhysicsCategory.step,  |= these characters confuse me. Can you elaborate what they mean as I am 5 years old?

Comment: At a high level, those statements set and unset a specific bit. In this case, they turn the category bit that corresponds to the `step` nodes on when the hero is falling and off when jumping. `x &= ~b010` is simply shorthand for `x = x & ~b010` and `x |= b010` is shorthand for `x = x | b010`, where &, ~, and | are the _and_, _not_, and _or_ bitwise operators, respectively. See [Bitwise Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID29) for a description of these operators.

Comment: Instead of `update` method, place it in the `didBeginContact` `didEndContact` methods,  save those precious cycles

Comment: @Knight0fDragon do you really believe that contact detection is free? In the simplest case (two circles), it will need to check the distance between the hero and ALL of the `steps` ~60 times a second. With more complex physics bodies, contact detection is significantly more involved.

Comment: The contact detection is happening regardless due to collision

Comment: Also, I do not believe distance is used in contact detection, it is a simple overlap check,  using the `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` may do that, but I doubt it.  I would assume it does line checks and see where both objects intersect, and evaluate at the time it takes one object to hit the intersect point if the other object is there as well.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon when jumping the hero isn't checking for collisions with my approach. That's ~50% of the time.

Comment: No see you cannot think like that, you always need to apply worst case scenario per update.  You can't tell somebody "My game only lags 50% of the time"

Comment: This approach is not going to cause a game to lag. Also, you can use the extra CPU cycles while jumping to scroll the world downward and to calculate the positions of future obstacles (for a game like Doodle Jump).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to go about this is to use 2 categories, let's call it `CollisionPlatform`, and `NoCollisionPlatform`.

Let's call your SKSpriteNode `Hero`

Set all platforms to `NoCollisionPlatform`

Your platform `SKPhysicsBody` should be a line, not a box.  It is better to use edge loops when creating these bodies, will put less strain on the physics world.

The `Hero` should only have `CollisionPlatform` in the `collisionBitMask`, but both `CollisionPlatform` and `NoCollisionPlatform` in the `contactTestBitMask`.

Your `Hero` should also know its previous position.

On your `didBeginContact` method, when you collide with `NoCollisionPlatform`, you check if the bottom of the `Hero` is equal to or below the platform and the previous position of the `Hero` is above the platform.  If this is true, then on your platform, change the `categoryBitMask` of the platform to CollisionPlatform

On your `didEndContact method` set the `categoryBitMask` of the platform back to `NoCollisionPlatform`

Now, be careful with how you do it, because if you move to the next platform that lies on the same x axis,  you may fall through due to rounding errors.  If you are not dealing with 1/2 pixel positions,  I recommend rounding or casting to `Int`

To achieve a forced down jump,  simply remember the last platform that the `Hero` was touching, and on the command, set the `categoryBitMask` back to `NoCollisionPlatform`.

At this point I would recommend sub classing your `Hero`, and keeping a pointer to the platform he last touched inside this sub class along with his previous position.  Be sure to clear it to nil when he no longer touches it.

Also note, that doing it this way means you do not need to apply any physics forces to your `Hero` other than gravity, so SKAction's will work hand in hand with this.  If you do not apply gravity, then I do not know what happens when you hit the platform, since the velocity of your `Hero` will be 0,  who knows what kind of push reaction (if any) will happen.  With going left and right (even up),  this will happen though, so what you can do is apply a small amount of velocity to your sprite so that the system knows the direction you are moving, but is weak enough that it won't move a pixel.

Doing all of this should also handle the side detection, since you only have 1 pixel to worry about for your platform, the chances of your `Hero` being above it the previous frame, and below it the next frame in such a way that you expect your `Hero` to not land on the platform is really slim (He would need to drop at an angle of like 1 degree over a good length of pixels in 1 frame to achieve this,  I say let the guy land in this case.

If you want to get even more advanced, reserve a bit on the mask to account for this, and just set when needed, this way you can have multiple categories, with only 1 reserved to do the collision test, instead of having to make multiple entries.  I like reserving bit 30 to handle this case, bit 31 I reserve to check if the sprite is alive or dead.

Do note that this will only work with 1 `Hero`

If you want to have multiple `Heroes`, then you have to work another way.

One is you do the swapping on the individual `Hero`'s `collisionBitMask` instead.  The problem with this approach is if you create a staircase of platforms, you may end up colliding into the side of the 2nd platform.

The other thing you can do, is use my advance method, and reserve certain bits of the `categoryBitMask` for each `Hero`