# How do I detect the direction of movement in sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Ok, for example's sake, lets say I have 2 `SKSpriteNode`s. So one of the `SKSpriteNode` is going up and bumping into the other. Both of them have `SKPhysicsBody`s. How do I make it so that if the first `SKSpriteNode` is touching the other `SKSpriteNode` from the bottom, then it should pass through, otherwise, the `SKSpriteNode` should stay solid. I have already tried detecting the direction, but the problem is that the `SKSpriteNode` is moving in multiple directions at once. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the sprite being moved by physics i.e. forces and impulses? If so, the physics bodies `velocity` property will have a value, and if `velocity.dy` is negative, then the body is moving up and if it's positive, then it's moving down. Similarly for left and right via the `velocity.dx` component.

Comment: This may be what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428866/one-way-platform-collisions-in-sprite-kit/39432431#39432431

Comment: @SteveIves dy > 0 indicates the body is moving upward

Comment: @0x141E Doh! Thanks. Too late to edit.

Comment: do you still need an answer for this Rishi?